# AWS EC2: external docker volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, devops

I have a typical web application written in Spring + React.

The `docker-compose` starts three containers:

1. Spring server
2. React client
3. PostgresQL server

Everything works fine locally, but I want to deploy it to AWS EC2 instance.

**The question:**

How do I handle the volume in the docker so that it is decoupled from the EC2 instance life-cycle? The volume has to be externalized from the EC2 instance's filesystem, because I need persistent database storage.

Should I use AWS EBS or what is typically used in such a scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Which volume are you referring to?  You could mount an EBS volume to your instance (and you'd have to keep track of it), or provision an RDS database (a little more expensive); these sorts of deployment-type questions aren't the sort of programming questions that are on-topic for Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: Probably more for SuperUser than SO question, but... Take a look at aws ECS - that has an EBS driver builtin so it can manage the data volume like you describe. You could also fake it by adding a 2nd EBS volume to the EC2 instance and just manage the docker volume yourself from script